# Undefined reference errors when including Rcpp.h

Tags: c++, r, g++, rcpp, include-path

I am using 64bit Ubuntu, and I am trying to write C++.

I discovered if I use `#include <Rcpp.h>`, I don't even need to call any functions in the R namespace, and I would already receive undefired reference errors:

```
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::xsputn(char const*, long)':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:61: undefined reference to `Rprintf'
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long)':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:65: undefined reference to `REprintf'
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::overflow(int)':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:70: undefined reference to `Rprintf'
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::overflow(int)':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:74: undefined reference to `REprintf'
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::sync()':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:79: undefined reference to `R_FlushConsole'
obj/x.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::sync()':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:83: undefined reference to `R_FlushConsole'
```

I have installed r-base and r-base-dev. I installed Rcpp by running R as root and did a `install.package("Rcpp")`

I compile the C++ program using g++ with `-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include`

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any replies.

Comment: You're missing a `-l<library>` (for whatever library is needed) and potentially `-L<path-to-directory-containing-library>`

Comment: R provides `R CMD SHLIB` for this.

Comment: @jsantander: Not just one. He is missing the entire R ecosystem.  Romain's answer and comment address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pulling `Rcpp` headers is not enough. You also need R headers and linking against R's library. You could use e.g. `R CMD SHLIB` to do this for you.

However, I'd suggest you either:

- create a package that has `LinkingTo: Rcpp` etc ... (see Rcpp's documentation).
- use `sourceCpp` on your `.cpp` file. See `?sourceCpp`

Comment: What you describe, especially the sourceCpp part sounds like many examples online to speed up R execution using C++, and calling C++ code from R.

Is there no way to only use R libraries in C++ without executing it in R?

Comment: No, there is not. You want to use R: use R.

Comment: There is [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which allows you to embed R within your C++ application, but that too still involves R as there is indeed no running R without running R.  Of course, you can peel respective algorithms and implementations out as it is Open Source (but do respect the licensing terms).

Answer (score 0):

As Romain Francois points out, you can't just have the headers (declarations), you also need the implementation.

What I suggest is to make a Makefile that produces a .so object. The R CMD SHLIB command is a good starting place to figure out which flags are needed, but it can't handle functions designed to be executed outside of Matlab.

Then, you need to find Rcpp.so and libR.so and link against both of them in your g++ call.

So, there is hope for "using R outside of R" -- in my case, I was able to compile some stuff from the VineCopula package into a .so file that Matlab was able to read.

See below for my Makefile (just as an example):

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/share/R/include/ -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/ -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/VineCopula/include -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR 
CFLAGS2=-I/usr/share/R/include/ -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/ -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/VineCopula/include 
LDFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g

all: RVinePDF.so

RVinePDF.so: RVinePDF.o Rcpp.so libR.so
  g++ $(CFLAGS) -o RVinePDF.so RVinePDF.o Rcpp.so libR.so $(LDFLAGS) 
  \rm *.o 

RVinePDF.o: RVinePDF.cpp 
  g++ $(CFLAGS2) -o RVinePDF.o -c RVinePDF.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

[other .o files defined similarly]
```